# Would like to insert a line break after every number in Notepad++ (or excel, or Word)

Tags: indexing, insert, notepad++, line, ocr

I've OCRed the index of a book, and it's worked well, apart from not recognising some line breaks. I would like to scan the indexes a load of books, and so need to add line breaks in using Notepad ++, ideally.

I have tried this in Find and Replace:

- Find what: `[0-9]+`
- Replace with: `\r\n`

Which  almost did what I want, but it removed the numbers.

it's more 'find numbers and insert line break after them' that I'm trying to do.

I would be so grateful for any help! Thank you!

Here's an example of the index before:

```
Bengali-style baked fish 77 biscuits: fennel seed drop-biscuits 155 bread: naan 129 roti 127 simple layered flat breads 126 broad bean thoran 112 burgers: chicken burger 43
```

And how I'd like it to look after:

```
Bengali-style baked fish 77 
biscuits: fennel seed drop-biscuits 155 
bread: naan 129 
roti 127 
simple layered flat breads 126 
broad bean thoran 112 
burgers: chicken burger 43
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Notepad++

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\d+ \K`
- Replace with: `\n` or `\r\n` for Windows EOL
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\d+         # 1 or more digits and a space
\K          # forget all we have seen until this position
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: oh my. It works. It works!!!!!! Thank you so very very much! This has made my week. Thank you :-)

Comment: @kathaurielle: You're welcome, glad it helps, feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)